# Div overlapping Bootstrap Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just starting to use Bootstrap.  Building my own page from scratch with it.

The problem I have is a div is overflowing a bootstrap container.

I don't know if I am designing this well in terms of how many columns I should be using or using a column instead of a div in some cases, I don't really understand the fine line yet between adding plain html inside columns and if I need nested Bootstrap columns, or if I'm going way overboard or not with columns and rows or if I dno't have enough...trying to understand that.  Because I could put a ton in ONE column but does one wanna do that, probably not and I'm trying to understand why or why not.

So obviously this is not fully responsive.

Anyway here is my code, and an image showing the overflow.

[image: Full Screen]

[image: Shrunk Browser]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>A Title</title>

    <link href="../../../content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../../content/bootstrap/css/sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../../content/bootstrap/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../../../content/bootstrap/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>

        body 
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .nopadding 
        {
           padding: 0 !important;
        }

        .padding-top-bottom-5
        {
            /* when to use important in bootstrap? */
           padding-top: 5px !important;
           padding-bottom: 5px !important;
        }

        .padding-left-5
        {
           padding-left: 5px !important;
        }

        .float-left{float: left;}

        .margin-5 { margin: 5px;}
        .margin-right-10 {margin-right: 10px;}
        .margin-2
        {
            margin: 2px !important;
        }

        .margin-left-5
        {
            margin: 2px !important;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 1em;
            line-height: 1.25em;
            text-align: justify;
            word-wrap: break-word;
         }

        .italic
        {
            font-style: italic;
        }

        .font-xsmall
        {
            font-size: 13px;
        }

        .bold
        {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        #castMetaList li
        {
            display: inline;
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }

        .vtop
        {
            vertical-align: top;
            float: left;
        }

        .inline-block
        {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .show-Details
        {
            float: right; 
        }

        .cast-description 
        {
            margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><img src="../../../Images/fullLogo_noBackground.png" />
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 well">
            <div id="navbar2" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Donate!</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid well">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar well">
                Getting Around
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar well">
                    <li class=" "><a href="#">Authors <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Recent shows</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Popular shiows</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-9 well">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-9 col-lg-12 well margin-2 padding-top-bottom-5">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xsm-4 col-sm-6 col-md-9 col-lg-12 well padding-top-bottom-5">
                                <img src="../../../Images/CastThumbs/episode206.jpg" class="vtop margin-right-10" />
                                <div class="show-Details">
                                    <span class="bold">The Title</span>
                                    <p class="cast-description">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. 
                                    </p>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xsm-4 col-sm-6 col-md-9 col-lg-12 well padding-top-bottom-5">
                                <p>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled" id="castMetaList">
                                        <li>2/17/2015</li>
                                        <li>Author: Some Dude</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xsm-4 col-sm-6 col-md-9 col-lg-12 well padding-top-bottom-5">
                                More details about this episode
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xsm-4 col-sm-6 col-md-9 col-lg-12 well padding-top-bottom-5">
                                Watch this episode
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xsm-4 col-sm-6 col-md-9 col-lg-12 well padding-top-bottom-5">
                                <img src="../../../Content/Bootstrap/fake_ad.jpg" width="468" height="60" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a site up we can look at?

Comment: I can, but I'm going to bed, I'll put it up tomorrow

Comment: Unfortunately by tomorrow you might not get any answers.

Comment: Provide us the site link to check the code

Comment: Providing a link to a live site is generally not recommended as when you fix it the problem won't be there for future visitors to see. Adding the code like you've already done is a better idea, or create a Bootply (www.bootply.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you are going a bit overboard with the columns. I couldn't reproduce your particular issue on Firefox but I did see other layout issues. Most issues were caused by your heavy mixing of different column sizes. In each `row` you should aim to make sure your `col-*` combinations add up to 12 at each size. You had huge numbers of different values for each of the size levels, when really you could have just made it simpler by only defining the sizes you needed.

I have created a Bootply that simplifies your code quite a bit. Instead of defining sizes for every single size breakpoint I only use the `col-sm` size. This means it will use the size you define until it hits the 'small' size, at which point it will break to full width. You'll find it much simpler to start with this kind of simple approach and only overlay more column sizes as and when you need them.

http://www.bootply.com/c8VpkBzHiI#

This is by no means a finished article. I've messed around with your Title section and turned it into a Bootstrap media object, but it didn't go responsive, but this can be a challenge for you to fix!

I hope this helps get you back in the right direction, and if you can tell us which browser you were having trouble with the overflowing text in and whether it still occurs with my code that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks!  I will check it out.  I thought having the different sizes are for each device type

Comment: I don't understand the media object at all...the docs suck on that topic

Comment: Looked at it, looks good but the reason I started to add extra column breaks is because I want it to look different for each device type.  I want the layout to be pretty different for an iPad for example vs. an IPhone.  On the mobile device I want to hide the left nav for example completely.  I have sketched out mocks of how it looks on each device, it's not all going to be stacked...not that simple meaningI'm not keeping the same stacked look for each md, lg, sm

Comment: Let me sketch the mocks just to show you my plans and I'll post those.

Comment: I've only tried this in Chrome so far.  I figured get it working there first then see how it's working in others.

Comment: You're using col-sm.  But I want to design this for phones too.  Shouldn't I be using xs?

Comment: can you explain the media stuff you added

Comment: My idea was to start basic, hence only using the col-sm classes. By all means start adding the other classes from then for different size devices. And yes, if you want different layouts for 'extra small' devices use the -xs- classes as well, just bear in mind that -xs- is very small, so you don't have a huge amount of screen real estate to play with. Just don't think you need different layouts for every screen size. Sometimes simple works best!